# Network alert trigger

Tags: network-monitor

Is there any program could packet sniff my network in certain times and log them. *eg. at 3am scan my entire network for an hour then log that in a file on my desktop.*

or alternatively and more specific if it can sort of monitor the network for unknown activity and that trigger alert and then start the scan and as well log in a file?  *eg. assuming there is whit-list **MAC Address filtered**. What would trigger the alert is when there is duplicate mac address on the network or the connection starts to go below certain ping, I'd like to record the incoming/outgoing packets ?*

Comment: What OS should it run on – or must it be cross-platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) - it allows you to capture, (sniff), packets, filter them based on almost any criteria, including the time of day, and log them, (plus a lot more), decode them, etc.

Features:

- Free
- Cross platform but you do need to ensure that dependencies are met
- Can put most network cards into promiscuous mode so as to capture "passing" traffic
- Very powerful

Comment: Trying it, will get back to you. Thanks @Steve

Comment: Works like a charm, Its even more better that its in Python and basically battery included.

Answer (score 0):

[Trogon MAC Scanner](http://trogonsoftware.com/trogon-mac-scanner.html) scans network for ip\mac addresses, compares with list of pre-saved mac\ip addresses and shows the unauthorized\doubled MAC addresses. Scheduled scanning can be run through the command line interface.